# Script bundles with 6MB loading failed in IIS deployment

Tags: iis, angular5, angular-cli

Can we split Script section in angular-cli.json or reduce scripts bundle size

can we split scripts section in to
"scripts1": [],
"scripts2":[]

**i'm having an issue with loading more than 6MB script bundle files.
Its not loading when deploy in IIS Express**

[please see the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fxVd.png)

Comment: are you deploying in IIS or IIS-express? and what is your base url? did you build an app before deployment?

Comment: i'm deploying in IIS and my application works fine in local

Comment: i've build application thats why i'm saying its working in local machine in my previous comment and created this issue for script with size more than 6mb is not loading in iis only

Comment: try to increase the iis site connectionTimeout limit. [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/sitedefaults/limits) and make sure your base URL is right.

Comment: already tried no use. it works some time when bandwidth is fast. but for users with low bandwidth script file not loading

Comment: you could try to minify your js file using a tool like [javascript minifier](https://javascript-minifier.com/).

Comment: No its infragistics.lob.js(2.56MB) from infragistics already provided as minimized lite version. i'll check related to network latency to keep connection on while load scripts and allow to fully load before move to next call